# Make Firefox 5 show current downloads in status bar (now "add-on bar")

Tags: macos, download, statusbar, firefox

In older Firefoxes when you downloaded a file it showed at the bottom of the window in the status bar. If you downloaded more than 1, it told you how many were remaining to be downloaded and the time left. Firefox 5 seems to have gotten rid of that feature.

Is there any way to get it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Download Statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-statusbar/). It is a free add-on for Firefox, and shows plenty of information, including what you want.

[image: download statusbar]

Comment: I've never even seen anything about downloads in Firefox without the use of an addon. I've used DSb for quite some time now, it's great!